# TypeORM ManyToOne relationship not saving

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

for some reason, one of my ManyToOne relationship not saving to DB. I have the following entity. The "by" relationship is saving just fine. But the evidence is not. I do have the evidenceId foreign key column in my table. But when I do entity.save(), the evidenceId is always null. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

```
@Entity('evidence_log')
export class EvidenceLogEntity extends Base {
  @ManyToOne(() => EvidenceEntity, evidence => evidence.logs)
  evidence: EvidenceEntity;

  @Column()
  action: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity)
  by: UserEntity;

  @Column()
  text: string;

  constructor(evidence?: EvidenceEntity, action?: string, by?: UserEntity) {
    super();
    this.evidence = evidence || this.evidence;
    this.action = action || this.action;
    this.by = by || this.by;
    this.text = this.text || this.by ? this.getText() : '';
  }

  getText(): string {
    return `${this.by.firstName} ${this.by.lastName} (${this.by.id}) ${this.action} Evidence "${this.evidence.name}"`;
  }
}
```